# How can I use ogrinfo to reach information about a .shp?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr, c++, visual-studio

How can I use ogrinfo?
where should I write it?
In the visual studio's command prompt or somewhere else?
Can you make some examples?

---

when I use `ogrinfo` in the windows or visual studio's command prompt, I get the result:

[image]
This is the same result that I get, when I use `gdal_translate`.

Answer (score 4):

ogrinfo as nothing to do with Visual Studio. It is a command line tool (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X)

So you use it in the Windows console or in the Linux and Mac OS X shell in the same way.

```
ogrinfo yourshape.shp
```

with a lot of options: ([ogrinfo](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html))

And, there are many, many tutorials in  [Gis.StackExchange : search ogrinfo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=ogrinfo) and on the Web....

Comment: ok thanks @gene but the reason that I asked the question is the problem I have explained now in my question. In fact, I have read some of those tutorials but each time, I get the same error. And as I have said in my question, afew days ago I couldn't use `gdal_translate`,too. If you're desired to help me please see my editing the question. thanks alot.

Comment: I do not use Windows but I suspect that you have a problem with the GDAL/OGR installation and the paths of the tools

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you must specify the full path to the ogrinfo executable. On my windows 7 machine it is: `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogrinfo`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your environmental variables for it to be recognised as a command by the command prompt.

See:
http://gisforthought.com/setting-up-your-gdal-and-ogr-environmental-variables/

Alternatively supply the full path to your GDAL/ogr install. Like:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogrinfo.exe myshapefile.shp
```

Or run the command from the same folder as your ogr/GDAL install.

```
cd "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\"
ogrinfo "C:\mydata\myshapefile.shp"
```

I would recommend reading up a bit on the windows command prompt in general. These are not really GIS issues.