# ogrinfo missing DLL error

Tags: ogr

When trying to execute "ogrinfo" command the following message appears:

```
the code execution cannot proceed because gssapi64.dll was not found. Reinstalling the 
program may fix this issue.
```

I have tried to reinstall gdal with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

But it did not solve. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you importing the module? Can you provide a bit more code on how you are running it? Command Line or Script?

Comment: Command Line, Windows cmd

Comment: Can you please provide some more information? What does your code look like. What version are you using. You might try uninstalling gdal and reinstalling it, not just reinstalling.

Comment: I am trying to execute some code, but before that I must make sure GDAL works correctly, how can I uninstall GDAL?

Comment: [conda method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459186/conda-uninstall-one-package-and-one-package-only) and [pip method](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/)

Comment: Binx, Thanks for quick answer. I deleted GDAL and installed it via conda, unfortunately it did not help. gssapi64.dll is missing error.

Comment: Can you post what you are entering into the command line? Or a picture of it? Could you also try installing gdal==3.0.2? I've had some problems with some gdal versions in the past.

Comment: Here is a print screen https://imgur.com/a/Pbk51hr . I am starting to think this dll is not related to GDAL...

Comment: you need to add your shapefile that you are trying to gain info from. Look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71394/how-can-i-use-ogrinfo-to-reach-information-about-a-shp)

Comment: Binx, I found a different solution to what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your solutions for others who run into this problem

Comment: Let me clarify - the problem was not solved. I just found a different approach rather than using ogr2ogr command line tool.

Comment: The same issue seems to happen here https://github.com/pythongssapi/python-gssapi/issues/193 but unfortunately I do not understand what is means.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I solved this problem with
**conda install krb5**

Comment: this worked for me! thanks